# How to enter character string vector in R plumber API

Tags: r, plumber

I'm building some API endpoints using R's Plumber. One thing I'm trying to learn is how to enter a strings as a vector.

Below is a simplified example of the problem. In this case, what I'd like is something like the following if this were pure R.

```
cols <- c('V1', 'V3')
tmp <- dat[, cols]
colMeans(tmp)
```

So, I built the following API, but when testing using Swagger when I enter something like V1, V2 into the cols argument it breaks and returns an error

```
library(plumber)
library(dplyr)
### Contents of plumber.r file
#* Do means
#* @param cols The columns I want
#* @get /mean
function(cols) {
    dat <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(10), V2 = rnorm(10), V3 = rnorm(10))
    tmp <- dat[, cols]
    colMeans(tmp)
}
pr("c:/path2file/plumber.R") %>%  pr_run(port=8000)
```

Can anyone suggest how a get request might pass something like "V1, V3" or something like that to the cols argument in this example that would index the columns of the dataframe at the /mean endpoint like the pure R example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SHORTER ANSWER

In your local machine reprex, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mean?cols=V1&cols=V2` would work.

## SHORT ANSWER

After `http://host:port/`, you can enter your `mean` function. To pass an array, enter `?param=value1&param=value2&param=value3...`

Comment: The answer above is correct and solves the problem and I have applied this to my real world scenario. Just curious, when using Swagger, there is one text input box to enter the "cols" argument. Just for purposes of testing the API inside Swagger, is it also possible to enter multiple values into that one text box as far as anyone is aware? If I enter "V1,V2" into that text box it doesn't work and it's now obvious why. It clearly works using something like curl, so I have a way to test this, but if possible in Swagger also I'd like to learn if it's doable.